# How to get django.db.connection.queries data from multi-processes(child-process)?

Tags: python, django, oracle11g

I am using `Django` `model` with `Oracle` and there are two processes having a DB connection respectively.

In order for both processes to have a DB connection respectively, I first close the connection in the main process before forking a process and then fork a new process so that it prevents child process to copy the DB connection.

```
    from django.db import connection 
    connection.close()

    childProcess.start()
```

As a result, each process re-open DB connection each when they first try to access the DB through Django model.

In this circumstance, In the main process it works fine with `django.db.connection.queries` returning query information in the process but in the child process it returns always an empty list.

How can I get query information in the child process using `django.db.connection.queries` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I go wrong with the problem I asked.

In the child Process, it creates a new Thread.

This Thread only does monitor the query operated by the main Thread(in the child Process).

I thought that `connection` object offered by `Django` is `global` resource in a Process.(that is why I separated the rule of Threads, one is to run queries and the other one is to monitor the queries).

However, after a series of test, I found that a `connection` object only collects query information operated by the Thread.

It means that `django.db.connection` run per a Thread not a process.

As a result, I mistook the problem's cause for Multi-processing problem.